# Can't reproduce HEVC (H.265) video without lags (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: nvidia, video, vlc, hevc, mpv-media-player

```
$ mediainfo file.mkv 
...
Complete name                            : file.mkv
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 4 / Version 2
File size                                : 48.6 GiB
Duration                                 : 2h 21mn
Overall bit rate                         : 49.2 Mbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-03-05 20:11:44
Writing application                      : mkvmerge v9.9.0 ('Pick Up') 64bit
Writing library                          : libebml v1.3.4 + libmatroska v1.4.5

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : HEVC
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Main 10@L5@Main
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC
Duration                                 : 2h 21mn
Bit rate                                 : 42.8 Mbps
Width                                    : 3 840 pixels
Height                                   : 1 600 pixels
...
```

I have tried both with VLC:

```
$ vlc --version
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
VLC version 2.2.7 Umbrella (2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1)
Compiled by buildd on lgw01-10.buildd (Jul 21 2017 14:48:51)
...
$ vlc file.mkv 
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
[00000000011e3088] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[00007f41d8d1f2a8] dts decoder: DTS channels:6 samplerate:48000 bitrate:1536000
Stream with high frequencies VQ coding
[hevc @ 0x7f41d8cea0a0] Could not find ref with POC 206
[hevc @ 0x7f41d8d0d700] Could not find ref with POC 213
[hevc @ 0x7f41d8cea0a0] Could not find ref with POC 249
...
```

and with MPV:

```
$ mpv file.mkv 
Playing: file.mkv
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (hevc)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 --alang=eng (*) (dts)
     Audio --aid=2 --alang=spa (ac3)
     Audio --aid=3 --alang=fre (ac3)
     Audio --aid=4 --alang=por (ac3)
 (+) Subs  --sid=1 --slang=eng (*) (hdmv_pgs_subtitle)
     Subs  --sid=2 --slang=spa (hdmv_pgs_subtitle)
     Subs  --sid=3 --slang=fre (hdmv_pgs_subtitle)
     Subs  --sid=4 --slang=por (hdmv_pgs_subtitle)
     Subs  --sid=5 --slang=chi (hdmv_pgs_subtitle)
     Subs  --sid=6 --slang=eng (hdmv_pgs_subtitle)
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz 5.1(side) 6ch float
VO: [opengl] 3840x1600 yuv420p10
AV: 00:29:39 / 02:21:29 (20%) A-V:  0.413 Dropped: 24

Audio/Video desynchronisation detected! Possible reasons include too slow
hardware, temporary CPU spikes, broken drivers, and broken files. Audio
position will not match to the video (see A-V status field).
```

But the video always lags... worst result with vlc.
And I don't think it a problem about hardware:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4712HQ CPU @ 2.30GHz
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] (rev a1)
```

I'm using the NVIDIA proprietary driver:
NVIDIA binary driver - version 384.90

I also tried with the nouveau driver, I installed the ubuntu-restricted-extras package, it's a laptop but I'm not using the battery... I have no more ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to this thread, posting number 4: https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/981372/geforce-basics/which-gpus-support-hevc-a-k-a-h-265-/

> Consumer Grade:
>   GeForce Support list (Feature Set "D" or higher only)
>   Feature set "D" supports H.264 (up to 4032 × 4048 pixels.)
>   Feature Set E,F, and H support H.265 (up to 8192x8192/8k resolution)

compared with the table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_PureVideo

> GT 750M -- GK107 -- VP5 -- **D** -- March 2012

your graphics card could be the cause.

```
The fifth generation PureVideo HD

The fifth generation of PureVideo HD, introduced with the GeForce GT 520 (Fermi
(microarchitecture)) and also included in the Nvidia GeForce 600/700 (Kepler 
(microarchitecture)) series GPUs has significantly improved performance when 
decoding H.264.[11] It is also capable of decoding 2160p 4K Ultra-High 
Definition (UHD) resolution videos at 3840 × 2160 pixels (doubling the 1080p 
Full High Definition standard in both the vertical and horizontal dimensions) 
and, depending on the driver and the used codec, higher resolutions of up to 
4032 × 4080 pixels.

The fifth generation PureVideo HD is sometimes called "PureVideo HD 5" or 
"VP5", although this is not an official Nvidia designation. This generation of 
PureVideo HD corresponds to Nvidia Feature Set D (or "VDPAU Feature Set D").
```

Comment: My fault! I did't realize that 5 years have already passed since my GPU was announced in [2013](https://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GT-750M.90245.0.html)...